# Updating master record with contents of detail record

Tags: trigger, formula, master-detail, roll-up-summary

I have a master detail relationship between accounts and a custom object, memberships. The membership object contains fields for start date, end date, membership package (picklist) and subscription amount.

How can I create a read only field on the account that says whether or not the account is an current member (based on the start and end dates of the membership) and the membership package they are on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a workflow rule on the membership object to run when the end date is greater than today. Then setup 2 time triggers, the first one for the start date that updates a checkbox field "isActive" on the Membership object with "True", the second one for the end date that would set the "isActive" to false. You could then use that field to rollup the child information to the parent when isActive = true.
Alternatively you could directly update the parent object from the child object with the time triggers, but you would probably want to have the end trigger run 1 hour before the end date in case you have multiple memberships one starting the same day as the other one ends.